# Error handling with imap_unordered in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use pool.imap_unordered from python multiprocessing to query an external service.  What I would like to do is split the input into smaller tasks if one fails. Right now I've got something like the following:

```
results = []
for result in pool.imap_unordered(query_service, tasks):
    results.append(result)
```

Does imap_unordered reraise exceptions, is result an exception if a child task fails or does it just retry continuously?

Comment: "split the input into smaller tasks if one fails" what do you mean? One process receives one task from your `tasks` list at a time.

Comment: When a task fails I want to divide the failed task into smaller sub tasks and resubmit them to the pool.

Comment: There are two problems here: 1. If one task fails, whole call to `imap_unordered()` fails and you won't get results from any of the pending tasks. 2. You can't add few more tasks into running `imap_unordered()`. You need to rethink your approach to handle this two problems.